# jquery fails to load php file

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jquery ajax for registration form. It was working couple of hours ago. I didn`t even make changes on it. But now google chrome says "failed to load resource". Here is the code that I use:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/funny_reg.php",  
                    type: "POST",       
                    data: data,     
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        alert("some text");
                    }   
                });
```

I have also tried to open funny_reg.php file directly and it says that the web page is not available.The file exists. I don`t know what to do.

Comment: If you can't reach the file by browsing it directly through the browser either, then the problem isn't in your JavaScript, it's probably in your server. Is your webserver running? Can you reach other files on the server?

Comment: Have you checked your server to see if funny_reg.php is still there? Sounds like it's been removed or something and the server's returning a 404

Comment: The problem was in one of the files that were included in funny_reg.php. There was an extra "\" symbol in regular expression. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to your url being a relative path. Try using an absolute path from your domain base. e.g:

`url: '/ajax/funny_reg.php'`